# WordPress filter posts using ajax at particular page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, post

I have made posts filter, which is working.
Also I made a pagination for posts, but if I want to filter posts just on current page, my code doesn't work anymore.
So I have pagination and if I filter posts in page 1, then filter take all posts from all pages.
For example I have Post 1 and Post 2 in the first page and Post 3 in second page.
If filter condition requirements suits for Post 1 and Post 3, I need to see only Post 1, because I'm in the first page and Post 3 is in second page. 
Now it shows Post 1 and Post 3 even if I am in first page.
Maybe any suggestions how to handle this?

index.php Code:

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select category&show_option_all=&name=cat1');
 ?>

 <?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select category&show_count=0&orderby=name&echo=1&taxonomy=initiative&name=cat2');
  ?>
    <?php 
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $args = array( 
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'paged' => $paged
    );

    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $posts->have_posts() ) : 
    ?>
        <?php while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post() ?>

            <?php  get_template_part('content'); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php  get_template_part('content','none'); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php   $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $posts->max_num_pages
    ) );

     ?>
    <?php 
            wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

JS Code:

```
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
var currentPage = <?php echo $paged; ?> ;                            
(function($) {

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form.posts-filter select').change(function(){

    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: ajaxurl,
            data:$('form.posts-filter').serialize()+'&paged='+currentPage+'&action=filter_posts', //only input
            success: function(response){
                $("#main-content .container").html(response);
            },
            beforeSend: function(){

            $('.loader').show(),
            $('.loader-fade').show()

            },
            complete: function(){

            $('.loader').hide(),
            $('.loader-fade').hide()

            }
        });
    });
    });


})(jQuery);
```

functions.php Code:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_posts', 'filter_my_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_posts', 'filter_my_posts'); 



function filter_my_posts(){

$filterId = $_POST['cat1'];
$filterId2 = $_POST['cat2'];  
$relation = '';

if (($filterId == '-1') || ($filterId2 == '-1')){

$relation = 'OR';

} else {

$relation = 'AND';

}


 if ( isset($_POST['paged']) ) {
        $page = $_POST['paged'];
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }    

$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'paged' => $page,
    'tax_query' => array(
     'relation' => $relation,

    array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $filterId
            ),
    array(
            'taxonomy' => 'initiative',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $filterId2
        )
    )

);

if (($filterId == "-1") && ($filterId2 == "-1")){

unset($args['tax_query']);

}

$posts = query_posts($args);

 if(have_posts()){

     while(have_posts()){ the_post();

            get_template_part('content');               

     } 
 }

 wp_reset_postdata();
die();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter posts throw ajax this way, you must send post_ids from first page to your filter function and then tell WP to do return result only from them.

So, in your args in `filter_my_posts` function must put in `$args` this row:

```
'post__in' => array($post1_id, $post2_id)
```

because otherwise WP only knows that must return particular number of posts (2 in your case) and of course, if POST1 and POST3 maches, it will return this two.

I don't know what must to do your filter, but after having all your posts already in the page maybe you can consider using js sorting like this for example [uikit](http://getuikit.com/docs/grid-js.html) (filtering sections) and avoid additional requests to server and DB.

Comment: It works, but not like I need. WP still return all posts, which requires filter condition, but WP doesn't understand, that I want to filter just current page posts e.x. at page 1, I need to filter posts just from page 1, but WP takes posts from all pages and returns that way.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting `posts_per_page` in your `$args` query?

```
$args = array( 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);
```